# loop categories with assigned forums

Tags: php, sql, mysql

**forumcats:** id, name
**forums:** id, name, cat_id

How can i join these together and print the forums assigned to the categories under them
Would really appriciate if someone could give me a hand

This is what i mean:

## A category

#### A forum

<

#### A forum

## A 2nd category

#### Another forum

#### Another forum

#### Another forum

## A 3rd catagory

#### Another forum

#### Another forum

#### Another forum

```
$reslt = mysql_query("select id, name, cat_id from forums");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($reslt)) {

 echo "<h1>Category here</h1<";
 echo "<h3>$row[name]</h3>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this query:

```
SELECT forums.*, forumcats.name AS category_name
FROM forums
INNER JOIN forumcats ON (forums.cat_id = forumcats.cat_id)
```

Then when you loop through the results, you want to identify when you've moved on to a new category.  For example:

```
$last_cat_id = null;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($reslt)) {
  if ($last_cat_id != $row['cat_id']) {
    echo '<h1>' . $row['category_name'] . '</h1>';
    $last_cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
  }
  echo "<h3>$row[name]</h3>";
}
```